# creating a new, empty document with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I'm working with some very unintuitive xml (all the tags are things like "TX", "H", "VC").

I'd like to make a copy of this data, but with all of the tags renamed to what they actually mean. Can I create a new, empty document to put my new, nicely named tags in to?

I've tried this:

```
doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString("", 'text/xml');
```

but when I do so, I wind up with a document that has a child node, rather than being empty. Furthermore, that child's tagname is "parsererror"

So, any ideas how I can create an empty document?

Answer (score 6):

I hade the same issue and I solved it like below:

```
xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
root = xmlDoc.createElement("description");
xmlDoc.appendChild(root);
alert((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an empty [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document) in a W3C DOM compliant browser (IE9+ and the rest) with the following code.

```
var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString('<dummy/>', 'text/xml');
doc.removeChild(doc.documentElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [WHATWG's specification of the `createDocument` method](//dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-domimplementation-createdocument) allows one to provide `null` for each of the 3 arguments to `createDocument`, to have an "empty" XML document created and returned -- one without any root node and with the `application/xml` as its content type.

When the `document` object is available (a compliant Web user agent), the implementation with the `createDocument` method can be referred to with `document.implementation`:

```
document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);
```

You may then trivially attach a root node of your choosing to it by simply appending it as you otherwise would, as follows (`empty_doc` would refer to the document created and returned by the call above):

```
empty_doc.appendChild(empty_doc.createElement("foobar"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can create a document without the root node. You could create a fake node:

```
doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString("<dummy/>", 'text/xml');
```

However, a better solution might be to create constants for the node names:

```
// Use different variable names, like RealTxName, if desired
var REAL_TX_NAME = "TX";
var REAL_H_NAME = "H";

...
doc.find (REAL_TX_NAME);
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I've thought about that approach to, and may wind up using it. I'm just taking a few steps in several directions to see which way looks/feels more promising.

Answer (score 1):

```
var xmldom = require('xmldom');
var tree = (new xmldom.DOMImplementation()).createDocument();
```