# jQuery lowercasing xml element names

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery is lowercasing all `name` attribute values.
I have HTML form in like this:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName">
<input type="text" name="lastName">
<input type="text" name="amountForName">
```

Trying to read it and create a xml with its value.
**jQuery**

```
$(section).find('input').each(function(i, field) {
                        console.log($(field).attr('name'));//prints 'firstName'
                        var $fieldName  = $.createElement($(field).attr('name'));
                        $fieldName.text($(field).val());

$.createElement = function(name)
            {
                console.log('Creating Element '+name); //prints 'firstName'
                return $('<'+ name +' />');
            }
```

But the xml elements loose came casing and I get

```
<firstname>himanshu</firstname><lastname>yadav</lastname>
```

How can I retain camel casing for node names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here:

```
xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
root = xmlDoc.createElement("description");
xmlDoc.appendChild(root);
alert((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc));
```

This is from here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/1752772/2391022

Also, check out here:
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_create.asp

Comment: That doesn't address the problem of the "tags" being forced to lowercase.  Your jsfiddle shows the attribute values retaining their case, which also isn't the problem.

Comment: My bad, I guess I misunderstood the question. You can't use jquery's dom building tools to create case sensitive items. This is because HTML isn't case sensitive. You're going to have to use a XML builder then. check my edit

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is for parsing and manipulating HTML, not XML.  Use a XML library for creating XML if that is what you want, or build it up yourself in a string.

```
var result='';
$(section).find('input').each(function(i, field) {
  console.log($(field).attr('name'));//prints 'firstName'
  var $fieldName = $(field).attr('name');
  result+='<'+$fieldname+'>'+$(field).val()+'</'+$fieldname+'>';
}
```

This is for example only.  In a real production system, you need to make sure both the fieldname and value are XML-encoded otherwise all kinds of bad things can happen.

Comment: jQuery lowercase element names again when I try `append` `result` to `$section` element.

Comment: That isn't valid.  You can't just place XML into a HTML page directly.  You would need to put it into a script tag with `type="text/xml"`

Comment: Additionally, you wouldn't append it to the script tag, you would need to use something like the .text property of the script tag or something. Append is for appending HTML elements.