# Spring MVC: Not able to send xml DOM to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Trying to build xml out of form values. Earlier I was building it with the help of jQuery. jQuery has a bug and then I have to build XML with plain javascript. But Now when I submit the form, browser hangs and request does not reach the controller.
**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes={"application/json", "application/xml", "text/xml", "text/plain"})
        @ResponseBody public String handleSave(@RequestBody String formData)
        {

            System.out.println("comes here");
            System.out.println(formData);



        return "SUCCESS";

    }
```

**jQuery**

```
$('form').submit(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: collectFormData(),
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type":"application/xml"
                        },
                        dataType: 'application/xml',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('Success:'+data)
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('jqXHR:'+jqXHR+'\n'+'textStatus:'+'\n'+textStatus+'errorThrown:'+errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
```

**CollectFormData**

```
function collectFormData()
            {
                $rootElement = $('<FormXMLDoxument/>');
                xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
                root = xmlDoc.createElement($('form').attr('name'));
                $('form').find('div.section').each(function(index, section) {
                    sectionElement = xmlDoc.createElement($(section).attr('name'));
                    $(section).find('input').each(function(i, field) {
                        fieldElement  = xmlDoc.createElement($(field).attr('name'));
                        fieldText=xmlDoc.createTextNode($(field).val());
                        fieldElement.appendChild(fieldText);
                        sectionElement.appendChild(fieldElement);
                    });
                    root.appendChild(sectionElement);
                });
                console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(root));
                return root;                    
            }
```

Everything works fine if I implement collectFormData with jQuery but then I loose camel casing on element names.
**Old collectFormData**

```
function collectFormData()
            {
                $rootElement = $('<FormXMLDoxument/>');
                $formElement = $.createElement($('form').attr('name'));
                $('form').find('div.section').each(function(index, section) {
                    var $sectionElement = $.createElement($(section).attr('name'));
                    $(section).find('input').each(function(i, field) {
                        console.log($(field).attr('name'));
                        var $fieldName  = $.createElement($(field).attr('name'));
                        $fieldName.text($(field).val());
                        $sectionElement.append($fieldName);
                    });
                    $formElement.append($sectionElement);
                });
                $rootElement.append($formElement);
                console.log('Form XML is '+$rootElement.html());
                return $rootElement.html();                 
            }
```

My question related to jQuery [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022753/jquery-lowercasing-xml-element-names/18023009)

Comment: Thinking outside the box here... I don't know offhand how to solve your initial problem. But... is submitting the data as XML a requirement? Could you instead submit the form data as a bean and convert it to XML once you get it into your controller?

Comment: Yes. XML structure is not defined here. XML elements defends upon the field name provided in the document. Then I will be mapping form xml values to existing model. Existing model is complex and one to one mapping will not be possible.

Comment: Himanshu, did you ever get this figured out? If populating a bean and decoding the key/value pairs to xml back on the server will work, let me know and I can give you some sample code. Are the elements you need in text fields? If so generating xml would be easy...

Comment: @wSchmidt Yes I have got it working but now Controller is coming back with another error. I have posted it http://goo.gl/sfFbv9