# Why is JavaScript setting my div content to lower case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am trying to save an example XML document in a hidden div, then populate a textarea on my web page with the XML document ready for posting. But as soon as Javascript holds the div contents, all my nodes are lower case which means they can't be read on the submitted page.

Why is the case changing when all I'm doing is:

```
$("#request").html();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dwfx7cp2/

```
<RequestQuote xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
```

turns into

```
<requestquote xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
```

Comment: why because html parser parses the html and renders it with lower case tags. If you want to retain same case then add an hidden input and then set the value as this xml and then get it. https://jsfiddle.net/dwfx7cp2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#request").val();
```

.

```
alert("Why is this all lower case?!:\n\n" + $("#request input").val());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dwfx7cp2/2/

Comment: Absolute chicken legend! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the browser parses and executes the XML once pasted inside the hidden div. You can prevent this from happening by telling the browser not to execute it by doing one of the following:

- Paste the XML into a `<textarea>`
- Paste the XML into a text `<input>`
- Paste the XML into a `<pre>`
- Use this snippet, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18023004/3307872)

```
xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
root = xmlDoc.createElement("description");
xmlDoc.appendChild(root);
alert((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc));
```

Comment: Thanks for trying - the above solution cracked it though.