# JS jQuery load XML to HTML page and don't loose TagName Letter Sensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, case-sensitive

I load XML to HTML5 page into div element
How can I save CaseSensitivity?
I need "**PersonInfo**" but after load XML to div I have "**personinfo**" in Chrome
If I load XML to textarea - it have original CaseSensitive inside textarea like this **"xml:FullName"**
But inside textarea don't work DOM and jQuery

My XML, that what I need on my page and work with DOM

```
<div>
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<DocXmlDoc>
  <PersonInfo>
    <xml:FullName>sachin</xml:FullName>
    <xml:AgeYear>21</xml:AgeYear>
  </PersonInfo>
  <PersonInfo>
    <xml:FullName>Akash</xml:FullName>
    <xml:AgeYear>18</xml:AgeYear>
  </PersonInfo>
</DocXmlDoc>
</div>
```

For any:
I will try (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml)
In **consolelog** and **alert** it works, but if try InnerHTML or appendChild, or Jq.HTML it will replace CamelCase to notcamelcase

```
$.get("xmlfile.xml", function( xml ) {
document.getElementById("div").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', xml);
```

or

```
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML('afterbegin', xml);
}, 'xml');
```

This function used XML parametr. If i try "html" parametr - CamelCase loose,
if I try "text" parametr its undefined.

How can I get Clean XML with CamelCase inside my page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery lowercasing xml element names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022753/jquery-lowercasing-xml-element-names)

Comment: HTML itself is not case-sensitive with regard to tags. See this question and the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022753/jquery-lowercasing-xml-element-names

Comment: Where do you get "personinfo" in Chrome? Where does the sensitivity get lost? Please add your code.

Comment: after $(div).html(xml) i have all xml tags lowercase